# Where is the first Lunar soil sample currently located?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, planetary-science, lunar-landing

During Apollo 11, the first manned lunar landing, a "contingency sample" was taken by Neil Armstrong. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_11):

> About seven minutes after stepping onto the Moon's surface, Armstrong collected a contingency soil sample using a sample bag on a stick. He then folded the bag and tucked it into a pocket on his right thigh. This was to guarantee there would be some lunar soil brought back in case an emergency required the astronauts to abandon the EVA and return to the LM

Where is this sample currently located?

Answer (score 13):

Most of the contingency sample is located at the [Lunar Sample Laboratory Facility](http://curator.jsc.nasa.gov/lunar/lun-fac.cfm) (LSLF) in the building 31N at the Johnson Space Center in Houston, Texas. They are listing it in their [catalog](http://curator.jsc.nasa.gov/lunar/lsc/index.cfm). The contingency samples are items number 10010 and 10021 - 10033, as you can see in [this](http://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11SampleList-1.jpg) list (see the last column - Returned Container - items "Cont.Bag" [Contingency Bag]).

Only the items 10030 and 10033 are missing in the LSLF catalog. Where are these remaining parts of the contingency bag, I don't know. [This](http://www.dvidshub.net/image/704024/lunar-samples-apollo-11-100305#.Uuukp_M1h9M) seems to suggest that the item 10030 could be in Washington, DC. At least partially, because the item 10030 was apparently split into 5 pieces, as indicated [here](http://www.lpi.usra.edu/lunar/samples/atlas/misc_view/?mission=Apollo%2011&sample=10030&source_id=S76-21142).